# Google Groups replies

Tags: email, google-groups

I have changed the settings of my Google Group, now my members are able to reply/reply all from emails as well. However, when members reply to my posts they get an error. A self replied message as follows

> group only accepts replies via Web UI1.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you asked it on 2011 and Google Groups changed recently some features...

But if you want to enable replies from all users on the new Google Groups interface (hey, I use it in Portuguese, so some words here would be synonyms of real options):

1. Enter the group and choose Manage
2. On Details > E-mail Options, change Post Answers to All Members, and press Save
3. On Details > New Members, check the checkbox New Users can Post, and press Save
4. On Permissions > Basic, on Post select All Members, and press Save
5. On Permissions > Post, on Post select All Members (if you have done 4th step, probably this one would be already done too, but once, when I was creating dozen of new groups, options from these steps, 4 and 5, were different, perhaps a momentary bug), and press Save
6. On Info > General, on Post Options, check the option to Allow E-Mail Posting
7. And finally, on Members > All Members, check if someone is not allowed to post (on Posting column). If so, select them and on Actions > Post Permissions select the default option.

Comment: I am searching for the inverse way, to disable replies to group, but to auto enable all group replies to the author or the group manager...